# (Laravel) Change Nova Resource name? (only on interface)

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-nova

I'm trying to change the display name of one Nova resource, without change the name from de database that it references. Only for View / interface purposes.

I checked the App\Nova*myResource*.php file and find this variable:

```
public static $title = 'newName';
```

But after change this the same old name still appears. Anyone knows how to resolve this? maybe I have just to type some comands with artisan. (I have alredy try to restart the server).

Comment: Nova resource - is a model ?

Comment: **Static** methods need to have **no effect** on the state of the object. They can have local variables in addition to the parameters.

Comment: @AndriiSukhoi yes, it seems like a model, but a Model from App\Nova

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Laravel nova docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/search/global-search.html#title-subtitle-attributes) states:

> When a resource is shown within the search results, the results will display the "title" of the resource.
> For example, a User resource may use the name attribute as its title. Then, when the resource is shown within the global search results, that attribute will be displayed.

E.g. if you have `User` resource, you can set `$title` to `email` and when you use a search, his e-mail will be displayed as an attribute identifying him:

[image]

To change resource's label you can overwrite `public static function label()` and `public static function singularLabel()` methods in your resource's class.

Before:

[image]

After:

```
/**
 * Get the displayable label of the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function label()
{
    return 'Customers';
}

/**
 * Get the displayable singular label of the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function singularLabel()
{
    return 'Customer';
}
```

[image]